# Catching "Load balancer does not have available server for client" after update Srping Boot to 2.4.2

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-feign

As always, I have a problem after the update ;). I updated Spring Boot to 2.4.2 and Spring Cloud to 2020.0.1. I have Eureka server and two microservices: main-service and analyzer-service. I have simple function to catch load balancing error (I use Netflix Eureka with Open Feign):

```kotlin
fun Throwable.catchFeignException(block: () -> Unit) {
    if (cause is ClientException) block()
    else throw this
}
```

But... There isn't `com.netflix.client.ClientException` :O. So, I modified this method to write an exception to logger:

```kotlin
fun Throwable.catchFeignException(block: () -> Unit) {
    logger.info("Throwable: $this")
    block()    
}
```

Eureka server and main-service was running (I didn't launch analyzer-service). I sent endpoint request to main-service which communicates with analyzer-service. Aaaand... It went to `FeignErrorDecoder` (custom ErrorDecoder):

```java
    private final ErrorDecoder defaultErrorDecoder = new ErrorDecoder.Default();
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FeignErrorDecoder.class);
    private final Gson gson = new Gson();

    @Override
    public Exception decode(String methodKey, Response response) {
        try {
            Response.Body responseBody = response.body();
            logger.info("responseBody: " + responseBody);
            if (responseBody != null) {
                errorMessage errorMessage = gson.fromJson(responseBody.asReader(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), ErrorMessage.class);
                logger.error(errorMessage);
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            logger.error("Unable to catch error from " + methodKey + " " + ex);
        }
        return defaultErrorDecoder.decode(methodKey, response);
```

In console log I got:

```
Throwable: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $
responseBody: Load balancer does not contain an instance for the service analyzer-service
```

`JsonSyntaxException` has been thrown because the deserializer couldn't translate the string "Load balancer does not contain an instance for the service" into an ErrorMessage object. Before updating, it didn't call `decode()` method at all and I got in console log:

```
Error while sending frames to analysis for id 1111, adding to queue. Reason: Load balancer does not have available server for client: analyzer-service
```

for method:

```java
   private void sendDataToAnalyze(List<DataRequest> toAnalyze, String networkAddress) {
        try {
            AnalyzedDataResponse analyzedData = analyzerProxy.analyzeDataRequests(toAnalyze);
            processAnalyzedFrames(analyzedData, networkAddress);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            CommonUtilsKt.catchFeignException(e, () -> {
                String id = toAnalyze.get(0).getId();
                logger.warn("Error while sending data to analysis for id {}, adding to queue. Reason: {}", sideNumber, e.getCause().getMessage());
                ConcurrentLinkedQueue<DataRequest> queue = frameAnalysisQueueMap.getOrDefault(id, new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>());
                queue.addAll(toAnalyze);
                frameAnalysisQueueMap.put(sideNumber, id);
                return null;
            });
        }
    }
```

Error is similiar to `responseBody`. I looked at [examples](https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/feign-eureka), I have similiar configuration (Difference is I'm using `EnableEurekaClient` instead of `EnableDiscoveryClient`).

My pom.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>app</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>app-client</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>app-client</name>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <name>Central Repository</name>
            <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <properties>
        <jjwt.version>0.9.1</jjwt.version>
        <kotlin.compiler.incremental>true</kotlin.compiler.incremental>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <kotlin.version>1.4.30</kotlin.version>
        <springmockk.version>3.0.1</springmockk.version>
        <junit-jupiter.version>5.7.1</junit-jupiter.version>
        <keycloak.version>12.0.2</keycloak.version>
        <hikaricp.version>4.0.1</hikaricp.version>
        <grpc.version>1.35.0</grpc.version>
        <testcointainers.version>1.15.2</testcointainers.version>
        <springfox.swagger.version>2.9.2</springfox.swagger.version>
        <poi.ooxml.version>5.0.0</poi.ooxml.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-session</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>junit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-messaging</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-messaging</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
            <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
            <version>${hikaricp.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-test-junit5</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit-jupiter.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>${junit-jupiter.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
            <version>${junit-jupiter.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ninja-squad</groupId>
            <artifactId>springmockk</artifactId>
            <version>${springmockk.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-netty</artifactId>
            <version>${grpc.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-protobuf</artifactId>
            <version>${grpc.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-stub</artifactId>
            <version>${grpc.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-tcnative-boringssl-static</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.36.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
            <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.14.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>30.1-jre</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>testcontainers</artifactId>
            <version>${testcointainers.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>${testcointainers.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>${testcointainers.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.2.18</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-reflect</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>${springfox.swagger.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>${springfox.swagger.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ar.com.fdvs</groupId>
            <artifactId>DynamicJasper</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ar.com.fdvs</groupId>
            <artifactId>DynamicJasper-core-fonts</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>${jjwt.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${keycloak.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-admin-client</artifactId>
            <version>${keycloak.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-core</artifactId>
            <version>${keycloak.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>${poi.ooxml.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>${poi.ooxml.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jfree</groupId>
            <artifactId>jfreechart</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-spatial</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>create</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <doCheck>false</doCheck>
                    <doUpdate>false</doUpdate>
                    <timestampFormat>{0,date,yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}</timestampFormat>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build-info</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <additionalProperties>
                                <encoding.source>UTF-8</encoding.source>
                                <encoding.reporting>UTF-8</encoding.reporting>
                                <java.source>${maven.compiler.source}</java.source>
                                <java.target>${maven.compiler.target}</java.target>
                                <buildNumber>${buildNumber}</buildNumber>
                                <timestamp>${timestamp}</timestamp>
                            </additionalProperties>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.os72</groupId>
                <artifactId>protoc-jar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.11.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <protocVersion>3.11.4</protocVersion>
                            <includeStdTypes>true</includeStdTypes>
                            <inputDirectories>
                                <include>src/main/resources</include>
                            </inputDirectories>
                            <outputTargets>
                                <outputTarget>
                                    <type>java</type>
                                </outputTarget>
                                <outputTarget>
                                    <type>grpc-java</type>
                                    <pluginArtifact>io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:${grpc.version}</pluginArtifact>
                                </outputTarget>
                            </outputTargets>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <compilerPlugins>
                        <plugin>spring</plugin>
                        <plugin>jpa</plugin>
                    </compilerPlugins>
                    <jvmTarget>1.8</jvmTarget>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>kapt</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>kapt</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceDirs>
                                <sourceDir>src/main/java</sourceDir>
                            </sourceDirs>
                            <annotationProcessorPaths>
                                <annotationProcessorPath>
                                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
                                    <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
                                </annotationProcessorPath>
                            </annotationProcessorPaths>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile</id>
                        <phase>process-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test-compile</id>
                        <phase>test-compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>kotlin-maven-allopen</artifactId>
                        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>kotlin-maven-noarg</artifactId>
                        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>report</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I don't know what I'm missing. Any tips and hints?

Comment: What are you dependencies on the feign client side?

Comment: @spencergibb I edited my original post and added pom.xml